# I'm looking to set up a table that provides four answers in string based on the input

Tags: excel

I don't know how to explain this over text, as I'm not very experienced in programming and have very limited understanding of code language but here goes.  I'm trying to write the code for a macro in Excel 2010 where you input a word, click a macro button, and then four answers are provided in the active cell's row. My current code looks like this:

```
Sub specs()

Dim var1 As String
Dim var2 As String
Dim var3 As String
Dim var4 As String
Dim var5 As String

var1 = ActiveCell.Value
var2 = ("I" & (ActiveCell.Row))
var3 = ("L" & (ActiveCell.Row))
var4 = ("P" & (ActiveCell.Row))
var5 = ("S" & (ActiveCell.Row))

If var1 = "T2PMA" Then var2 = ">10.7" _
    And var3 = "3.0-5.0%" _
    And var4 = "5.3%" _
    And var5 = ">96.9%"

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use a Sub or Function, or if the If Then statement is the right way to go, or if I should try a loop.  This is where I am stuck.  Any help will be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to believe that your code works at all.

In particular, this part:

```
If var1 = "T2PMA" Then var2 = ">10.7" _
   And var3 = "3.0-5.0%" _
   And var4 = "5.3%" _
   And var5 = ">96.9%"
```

It seems that you want to check the value in `var1` and then assign the values in the other variables... But once you have typed `THEN` , you can not use the logical operator `AND` is if you want to continue your logical test..

You might have wanted to do this:

```
If var1 = "T2PMA" Then 
   var2 = ">10.7" 
   var3 = "3.0-5.0%" 
   var4 = "5.3%" 
   var5 = ">96.9%"
End If
```

Anyways, nothing happens to the user as far as your code goes. Did you want to output the 4 variables to the adjacent cells?

You should use a Function if you want to call it from another sub, module, to do further work.

In your case, you might want to overwrite the values in `Activecell.Offset(y,x)`

and so on.

Comment: That's basically what I meant, is that it doesn't work haha they aren't the adjacent cells